# Puzzled by Function body evaluation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am puzzled by the following behavior of `Function`:

```
In[1]:= InlineCellInMessage=Function[expr,DisplayForm[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr,StandardForm]],"Input"]],{HoldAllComplete}]
Out[1]= Function[expr,MakeBoxes[expr,StandardForm]]
```

I expected to see unevaluated code inside `Function` in the output as in the following case:

```
In[2]:= InlineCellInMessage=Function[x,x+1+1]
Out[2]= Function[x,x+1+1]
```

But I get the inline cell inside output. Why does this happen?

Comment: Try to use `InlineCellInMessage := Function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of FrontEnd rendering.  Consider:

```
InlineCellInMessage = 
  Function[expr,DisplayForm[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr,StandardForm]],"Input"]],{HoldAllComplete}]

InlineCellInMessage // InputForm
```

Output:

```
InputForm[Function[expr, DisplayForm[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]], "Input"]], {HoldAll.Complete}]]
```

Also, in this use the parameter `HoldAllComplete` affects future input to the function, not the creation of the function itself.  If you want `Function` itself to have `HoldAllComplete` you need:

```
SetAttributes[Function, HoldAllComplete]
```

Comment: Interesting, `HoldAllComplete[DisplayForm[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]], "Input"]]]` is also rendered. Is there a way to control this behavior?

Comment: I was unaware that we can directly set attributes to built-in `Protect`ed functions. Thank you for the point!

Comment: The most direct route is to use `// InputForm` as I did, but I presume you want different behavior.  Please be specific.

Comment: I just wish to understand what types of expressions FrontEnd renders automatically. I found that even `HoldAllComplete[Style[DisplayForm[Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]], "Input"]], Red]]` is auto-rendered. It is very surprizing for me since `Style` is not a low-level construct. From the other side, `MakeBoxes[expr, StandardForm]` is not a valid low-level expression for `BoxData`. How all of this works?

Comment: When the FrontEnd finds a `Style` expression within a StandardForm cell (for example), it automatically applies the style as instructed.  This is not limited to `Style` and includes instructions such as `Rotate`.  Try: `HoldAllComplete[Rotate[Style[expr, Red], 0.5]]`

Comment: Interestingly, the output has completely another internal structure (press Ctrl+Shift+E) than input. If we copy-paste the output then the `InputForm` of the expression we get will differ from the original input. Is this new expression created by the FrontEnd?

Comment: Is it possible to get complete list of expressions that are parsed by the FrontEnd automatically?

Comment: @Alexey I don't know.  I think that is worthy of posting to another question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have created [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617685/conversion-of-expressions-by-the-frontend) on this.