# Conversion of expressions by the FrontEnd

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

As I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616305) recently there are some types of expressions in *Mathematica* which are automatically parsed by the FrontEnd.

For example if we evaluate `HoldComplete[Rotate[Style[expr, Red], 0.5]]` we see that the FrontEnd does not display the original expression:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to control such behavior of the FrontEnd?

And is it possible to get complete list of expressions those are parsed by the FrontEnd automatically?

---

#### EDIT

We can see calls to `MakeBoxes` when using `Print`:

```
On[MakeBoxes]; Print[HoldComplete@Rotate["text", Pi/2]]
```

But copy-pasting the printed output gives changed expression: `HoldComplete[Rotate["text", 1.5707963267948966]]`. It shows that `Print` does not respect `HoldComplete`.

When creating output `Cell` there should be calls for `MakeBoxes` too. Is there a way to see them?

Comment: I don't agree with the statement that FrontEnd does not display the original expression in this case. What you see is purely a display mode, it does not modify the code itself in any way. For example, the `InputForm` shows that the expression is unchanged. Which leads to the question: why does this FE behavior bother you - which goals does it prevent you from accomplishing? Regarding the list of heads for which similar things happen, you can look at say `WrappersDump``WrapperToBoxes` definition (not sure if those exhaust the list).

Comment: Alexey, good catch regarding `HoldComplete` vs `HoldAllComplete` !

Comment: @Leonid In which cases this "display mode" plays the role? In which it does not? How it works? All of these are the questions I am interested in.

Comment: @Alexey  Most of what FrontEnd does is related to this or that type of boxes. For example, `Rotate` has a special `RotateBox`, which instructs FE to treat its content differently for presentational purposes. The fundamental functions relating boxes and expressions are `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression`. As long as you base your work on expressions, you can probably ignore the specific FE representation of them, unless the `MakeExpression@MakeBoxes` cycle produces something other than `HoldComplete[original_expression]`, in which case you may want to investigate it and find out the reason.

Comment: @Leonid But `Rotate` inside of the `HoldComplete` will not be transformed into `RotateBox`. It indicates that in really the FrontEnd also parses constructs other than explicitly in the form of `Boxes`. It is really unexpected behavior...

Comment: @Alexey  I actually misspelled the name - it is `RotationBox`, not `RotateBox`. And yes, `Rotate` does get transformed into `RotationBox` inside `HoldComplete` in `StandardForm` (default). To see that, look at the box expression of the resulting output cell (CTRL+SHIFT+E).

Comment: @Leonid Conversion is made purely in the kernel: `link=LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"];LinkRead[link];LinkWrite[link,Unevaluated[EnterExpressionPacket[SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> StandardForm];HoldComplete[Rotate[Style[expr, Red], 0.5]]]]];LinkRead[link]; LinkRead[link]`. I was unaware that there are such conversion rules. It obviously contradicts `HoldComplete` documentation. How can it work inside `HoldComplete`?

Comment: @Alexey  I am not convinced by your example. What I think is happening is that the resulting expression you are getting from the link is the same as the input one - that is, no conversion is taking place in the kernel. It is when the output cell is formed and perhaps internal rules for `MakeBoxes` fire, that the conversion to boxes  takes place, just as in previous cases, and of course with the same result.  If you wrap `FullForm` around the last `LinkRead[link]`, you'll  see that you are getting back the original expression.

Comment: @Leonid Do you mean that conversion is made by the FrontEnd that has its own analog of the evaluator with some definitions for FrontEnd's `MakeBoxes`?

Comment: @Alexey I don't know how the FE works in enough detail to answer that. What I meant is that FE somehow initiates the call to `MakeBoxes`, to produce the output cells in the notebook. Even if this happens in the kernel, this is probably a separate evaluation, after the main result is produced by the kernel as an expression. It is in this sense that I meant that the main evaluation done in the kernel is in agreement with the docs on `HoldComplete`. Once again - if we consider evaluation of expressions (and not their conversion into boxes), the evaluation is as documented.

Comment: @Leonid How had you found that ``WrappersDump`WrapperToBoxes`` is related to the conversion of output expressions?

Comment: @Alexey I looked at the top-level code for `Rotate`. You can do that by clearing its `ReadProtected` attribute.

Comment: @Leonid We can see calls to `MakeBoxes` when using `Print`: `On[MakeBoxes]; Print[HoldComplete@Rotate["text", Pi/2]]`. But copy-pasting the printed output gives changed expression: `HoldComplete[Rotate["text", 1.5707963267948966]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a [post by John Fultz](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jan/msg00427.html) with pretty clear explanation of how graphics functionality works:

> In version 6, the kernel has
>   absolutely no involvement whatsoever
>   in generating the rendered  image. 
>   The steps taken in displaying a
>   graphic in version 6 are very much
>   like  those used in displaying
>   non-graphical output.  It works as
>   follows:
>
> 1) The expression is evaluated, and
>   ultimately produces something with
>   head `Graphics[]` or `Graphics3D[]`.
>
> 2) The resulting expression is passed
>   through `MakeBoxes`.  `MakeBoxes` has a
>   set of rules which turns the graphics
>   expression into the box language which
>   the front  end uses to represent
>   graphics.  E.g.,
>
> ```
> In[9]:= MakeBoxes[Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}]}], StandardForm]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Out[9]= GraphicsBox[{PointBox[{0, 0}]}]
> > ```
>
> Internally, we call this the "typeset"
>   expression.  It may be a little weird
>   thinking of graphics as being
>   "typeset", but it's fundamentally the
>   same  operation which happens for
>   typesetting (which has worked this way
>   for 11  years), so I'll use the term.
>
> 3) The resulting typeset expression is
>   sent via MathLink to the front end.
>
> 4) The front end parses the typeset
>   expression and creates internal
>   objects which generally have a
>   one-to-one correspondence to the
>   typeset expression.
>
> 5) The front end renders the internal
>   objects.

This means that the conversion is performed in the Kernel by a call to `MakeBoxes`.

This call can be intercepted through high-level code:

```
list = {};
MakeBoxes[expr_, form_] /; (AppendTo[list, HoldComplete[expr]]; 
    True) := Null;
HoldComplete[Rotate[Style[expr, Red], 0.5]]
ClearAll[MakeBoxes];
list
```

Here is what we get as output:

[image: screenshot]

One can see that `MakeBoxes` does not respect `HoldAllComplete` attribute.

The list of symbols which are auto-converted before sending to the FrontEnd one can get from `FormatValues`:

```
In[1]:= list = 
  Select[Names["*"], 
   ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
     Function[symbol, Length[FormatValues@symbol] > 0, HoldAll]] &];
list // Length

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::readp: Symbol I is read-protected. >>

Out[2]= 162
```

Comment: +1 for the useful info, but I still disagree with your conclusion from the above that "`MakeBoxes` does not respect `HoldAllComplete` attribute". What we see is a display mode, if you use `FullForm` on `list`, you will see the original expression. I don't think there is any function in the whole mma language that (intentionally, by design, rather than due to some bug) does not respect any of its attributes - this would be a very big deal otherwise, would greatly undermine the language consistency. The users should not even be able to write such a function, and neither should the developers.

Answer (score 5):

There are two aspects to what you witness. First, transcription of the expression you entered into boxes and rendering those boxes by Front-End. By default the output is typeset using StandardForm, which has a typesetting rule to render graphics and geometric transforms. If you use InputForm, there are no such rule. You can control which form is used via Preferences->Evaluation.

You can convince yourself that HoldComplete correctly did its job by using InputForm or FullForm on the input, or using InputForm display on the output cell.

[image]

**EDIT** Using the OutputForm:

In[13]:= OutputForm[%]

Out[13]//OutputForm= HoldComplete[Rotate[expr, 0.5]]

In regard to your question about complete list of symbols, it includes Graphics, geometric operations, and possibly others, but I do not know of the complete list.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer, but in Preferences > Evaluation there are options to "Only use textual boxes when converting  (input|output) to typeset forms."

If you check these, then using Cell > Convert To... > StandardForm etc... will show the Rotate[..] instead of the visually rotated result.

Answer (score 1):

John Fultz has recently [answered](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/InIytzQPzb0/discussion) my question on converting `TableForm` to "typeset" expressions and it is worth to cite it here since it amplifies (while partially contradicts) the general explanation cited in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617685/conversion-of-expressions-by-the-frontend/5814442#5814442):

> `ToBoxes` is returning precisely what
>   the kernel sends to  the front end
>   without variation (except, in the
>   general case, for the evaluation 
>   semantics and side effects possibly
>   being different, but that's not an
>   issue in  your example).
>
> The issue is that the front end has
>   two different specifications for
>   specifying `GridBox` options... one of
>   which dates back to version 3, and the
>   other, more  expansive set dates to
>   version 6.  The front end understands
>   both sets of  options, but
>   canonicalizes anything it receives to
>   the version 6 options.
>
> `GridBox` is the only box which has had
>   such a wholesale change of options,
>   and it  was necessary to support new
>   functionality we added in v6.  But the
>   front end  will continue to understand
>   the old options for a seriously long
>   time (probably  forever), as the old
>   options show up not only in certain
>   kernel typesetting  constructs, but in
>   legacy notebook files.
>
> `ToBoxes[]` of `TableForm` is creating the
>   legacy options, as there's been no
>   need  to update the typesetting of
>   `TableForm` in a while (`ToBoxes[]` of
>   `Grid`, on teh  other hand, uses modern
>   options).  The conversion is done by
>   the front end.  You  could rely on the
>   front end to do the conversion for
>   you, or you could figure  out how the
>   options map yourself.

So in this case the final stage of the conversion of the expression is done by the FrontEnd.