# Making customized InputForm and ShortInputForm

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

I often wish to see the internal representation of *Mathematica*'s graphical objects not in the `FullForm` but in much more readable `InputForm` having the ability to select parts of the code by double-clicking on it and easily copy this code to a new input `Cell`. But the default `InputForm` does not allow this since `InputForm` is displayed by default as a `String`, not as *Mathematica*'s code. Is there a way to have `InputForm` displayed as *Mathematica*'s code?

I also often wish to see a shortened version of such `InputForm` where all long lists of coordinates are displayed as the first coordinate followed by number of skipped coordinate values wrapped with `Skeleton`, all empty `Lists` removed and all numbers are also shortened for displaying no more than 6 digits. It would be even better to use 6 digits only for coordinates but for color directives such as `Hue` display only 2 significant digits. For example,

```
Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // ShortInputForm
```

should give:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[{{1.28228`*^-7, 1.28228*^-7}, <<1133>>}, 
    {{{EdgeForm[], Directive[{Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}], 
          GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{1133, <<578>>}}]}]}, 
        {EdgeForm[], Directive[{Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}],              
     GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{432, <<556>>}}]}]}}, {{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 
      0.6], Line[{1, <<431>>}]}, {Hue[0.91, 0.6, 0.6], 
          Line[{432, <<701>>}]}}}], {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-1., 1}}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

(note that `-0.9999998592131705` is converted to `-1.`, `1.2822827157509358*^-7` is converted to `1.28228*^-7` and `Hue[0.9060679774997897, 0.6, 0.6]` is converted to `Hue[0.91, 0.6, 0.6]`).

In this way, I wish to have the output of `InputForm` as *Mathematica*'s code and also have a `ShortInputForm` function which will give the shortened version of this code. Can anybody help me?

---

As to the first part of the question, I have found one way to achieve what I want:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] //
   InputForm // StandardForm
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Mathematica's code"?  The most basic representation is FullForm, and you have already said that Fullform is not what you want.

Comment: @DeepYellow If you evaluate `Table[a, {100}] // InputForm` you will get output `Cell` in which you cannot select the whole expression by double-clicking on it. Pressing Ctrl+Shift+E shows that the `Cell` expression has the form: `Cell["\<\{a, ... a}\\>", "Output"]`. But if you evaluate  `Table[a, {100}]` you will get another `Cell` expression: `Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"a", ",", ..., "a"}], "}"}]], "Output"]`. As I understand in the first case `Cell` contains just a `String` but in the second it contains *Mathematica*'s code (the FrontEnd "understands" this as code).

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention to `Short` if you're not yet aware of it.  This doesn't really solve your problem though. `Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] //
   InputForm // (Short[#, 10] &)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### UPDATE

The most recent version of the `shortInputForm` function can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280).

---

### Original post

Here is another, even better solution (compatible with *Mathematica* 5):

```
myInputForm[expr_] := 
 Block[{oldContexts, output, interpretation, skeleton},
  output = ToString[expr, InputForm];
  oldContexts = {$Context, $ContextPath};
  $Context = "myTemp`"; $ContextPath = {$Context};
  output = DisplayForm@ToBoxes[ToExpression[output] /.
      {myTemp`interpretation -> If[$VersionNumber >= 6,
         System`Interpretation, System`First@{#} &],
       myTemp`Row -> System`Row,
       myTemp`skeleton -> System`Skeleton,
       myTemp`sequence :> (System`Sequence @@ # &)}, StandardForm];
  {$Context, $ContextPath} = oldContexts; output]
shortInputForm[expr_] := myInputForm[expr /. {{} -> Sequence[],
    lst : {x_ /; VectorQ[x, NumberQ], y__} /;
      (MatrixQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 3) :>
     {x /. v : {a_, b__} /; Length[v] > 3 :>
        {a, interpretation[skeleton[Length[{b}]], sequence@{b}]},
      interpretation[skeleton[Length[{y}]], sequence@{y}]},
    lst : {x_, y__} /; VectorQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 3 :>
     {x, interpretation[skeleton[Length[{y}]], sequence@{y}]}}]
```

### How it works

This solution is based on simple idea: we need to block conversion of such things as `Graphics`, `Point` and others [to typeset expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617685/conversion-of-expressions-by-the-frontend/5814442#5814442) in order to get them displayed in the internal form (as expressions suitable for input). Happily, if we do this, the resulting `StandardForm` output is found to be just formatted (two-dimensional) `InputForm` of the original expression. This is just what is needed!

But how to do this?
First of all, [this conversion is made by `FormatValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617685/conversion-of-expressions-by-the-frontend/5814442#5814442) defined for `Symbol`s like `Graphics`, `Point` etc. One can get full list of such `Symbol`s by evaluating the following:

```
list = Symbol /@ 
  Select[DeleteCases[Names["*"], "I" | "Infinity"], 
   ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
     Function[symbol, Length[FormatValues@symbol] > 0, HoldAll]] &]
```

My first idea was just `Block` all these `Symbol`s (and it works!):

```
myInputForm[expr_] := 
 With[{list = list}, Block[list, RawBoxes@MakeBoxes@expr]]
```

But this method leads to the evaluation of all these `Symbol`s and also evaluates all `FormatValues` for all `Symbol`s in the `$ContextPath`. I think it should be avoided.

Other way to block these `FormatValues` is just to remove context `` "System`" `` from the `$ContextPath`. But it works only if these `Symbol`s are not resolved yet to the `` "System`" `` context. So we need first to convert our expression to `String`, then remove `` "System`" `` context from the `$ContextPath` and finally convert the string backward to the original expression. Then all new `Symbol`s will be associated with the current `$Context` (and `Graphics`, `Point` etc. - too, since they are not in the `$ContextPath`). For preventing context shadowing conflicts and littering the `` "Global`" `` context I switch `$Context` to `` "myTemp`" `` which can be easily cleared if necessary.

This is how `myInputForm` works.

Now about `shortInputForm`. The idea is not just to display a shortened version of `myInputForm` but also preserve the ability to select and copy parts of the shortened code into new input cell and use this code as it would be the full code without abbreviations. In version 6 and higher it is possible to achieve the latter with `Interpretation`. For compatibility with pre-6 versions of `Mathematica` I have added a piece of code that removes this ability if `$VersionNumber` is less than 6.

The only problem that I faced when working with `Interpretation` is that it has no `SequenceHold` attribute and so we cannot simply specify `Sequence` as the second argument for `Interpretation`. But this problem can easily be avoided by wrapping sequence in `List` and then `Apply`ing `Sequence` to it:

```
System`Sequence @@ # &
```

Note that I need to specify the exact context for all built-in `Symbol`s I use because at the moment of calling them the `` "System`" `` context is not in the `$ContextPath`.

This ends the non-standard decisions taken me in the development of these functions. Suggestions and comments are welcome!

[image]

Comment: Alexey, I voted for both this and the question, but I think you should add an explanation of what this does, and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I have come to the following solution:

```
round[x_, n_] := (10^-n*Round[10^n*MantissaExponent[x]]) /.
   {m_, e_} :> N[m*10^e];
ShortInputForm[expr_] := ((expr /.
       {{} -> Sequence[],
        lst : {x_ /; VectorQ[x, NumberQ], y__} /;
          (MatrixQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 2) :>
         {x, Skeleton[Length[{y}]]},
        lst : {x_, y__} /; VectorQ[lst, NumberQ] && Length[lst] > 2 :>
         {x, Skeleton[Length[{y}]]}} /.
      {exp : Except[List | Point][x__] /; 
         VectorQ[{x}, MachineNumberQ] :>
        (round[#, 2] & /@ exp), 
       x_Real /; MachineNumberQ[x] :> round[x, 6]})
    // InputForm // StandardForm)
```

Now:

[image: screenshot]